# write latex symbols to label the x and y axis of a graph

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I am using matplotlib to plot a graph.

I want to label the x-axis any y-axis using latex symbols.

Can I do that?

```
`x= np.array([1,2,5,7])
y= np.array([6,6,8,9])
plt.xlabel(r'$\mathscr{L}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\mathrm{s}$')`
```

Comment: As you might be aware of, you need dollar signs to enter mathmode. `r'$\mathscr{L}$'`.

Comment: Yes I tried this sign in the beginning but it didn't work So I omit this.

Comment: You are missing a `\\` in the second command.

Comment: But still it doesn't work

Comment: Your code produces [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dANY.png) which shows the desired symbols.

Comment: In my original code I was also using \textit so it was not working. I'm not sure is there any limitation of using Latex symbols

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html